# Ubuntu Server not using proxy settings

Tags: networking, wireless, server, apt, proxy

i am using the ubuntu server package (terminal only) and i am struggling to get the proxy server working.

there is no username/password for the proxy.

When i am trying to do `sudo apt-get update` i get multiple errors like:

```
Failed to fetch blablabla... Cannot initiate the connection to proxy:8080 (proxy). - connect (101: network is unreachable)
```

In `/etc/enviroment` i have:

```
http_proxy="http://proxy:8080/";
https_proxy="https://proxy:8080/";
ftp_proxy="ftp://proxy:8080/";
```

when i do `$http_proxy` it returns `http_proxy="http://proxy:8080/";`

i have set the `/etc/gai.conf` to prefer IPv4 by putting `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100`

I'm using wireless but i have ethernet available. It does not recognise the ethernet though. The setup asked for the proxy and it accepted it (not sure if it used it or not).

edit: `route -n` gives:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway     Genmask     Flags Metric Ref     Use Iface
```

Comment: I assume "proxy" is a placeholder for the proxy's IP address? Could you show the output (add it to your question) of running `route -n` ? Also, if you could tell us the proxy's IP address, that'd be good, but not necessary if you have any reason for wanting to keep it secret.

Comment: Yes "proxy" is a placeholder. We are a school and use the councils proxy, not secret as such but it's not my place to put it up on the internet.

Comment: Ok, your routing table is wrong as it doesn't show anything :( this means your network interface is misconfigured and not actually up, which explains the "network unreachable" report. Do you have any internal web servers you can check without setting the proxy? this will let you solve one problem at a time, because right now, the problem is that you're not really connected to any networks. For completeness, here's an example of how your routing table should look like, once a wlan0 interface is up and has a default route: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10160311/

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to set the proxy specifically for apt, see [this ubuntu documentation link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy) which the source for the following:

> ***Setting up apt-get to use a http-proxy***
>
> These are three methods of using apt-get with a http-proxy.
>
> **Temporary proxy session**
>
> This is a temporary method that you can manually use each time you want to use apt-get through a http-proxy. This method is useful if
>   you only want to temporarily use a http-proxy.
>
> Enter this line in the terminal prior to using apt-get (substitute your details for  your proxy address and proxy port):>
>
> `export http_proxy=http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport`
>
> If you normally
>   use sudo to run apt-get you will need to login as root first for this
>   to work unless you also add some explicit environment settings to
>   /etc/sudoers, e.g.
>
> Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
>
> **APT configuration file method**
>
> This method uses the apt.conf file which is found in your /etc/apt/
>   directory. This method is useful if you only want apt-get (and not
>   other applications) to use a http-proxy permanently.
>
> On some installations there will be no apt-conf
>   file set up. This procedure will either edit an existing apt-conf file
>   or create a new apt-conf file.
>
> Add this line to your /etc/apt/apt.conf file (substitute your details for your proxy address and proxy port).
>
> `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";`
>
> Save the apt.conf file.
>
> **BASH rc method**
>
> This method adds a two lines to your .bashrc file in your $HOME
>   directory. This method is useful if you would like apt-get and other
>   applications for instance wget, to use a http-proxy.
>
> Add these lines to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file (substitute your details for your proxy address and proxy port)
>
> `http_proxy=http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport export http_proxy`
>
> Save the file. Close your terminal window and then open another terminal
>   window or source the ~/.bashrc file:
>
> source ~/.bashrc Test your proxy with sudo apt-get update and whatever
>   networking tool you desire. You can use firestarter or conky to see
>   active connections.
>
> If you make a mistake and go back to edit the file again, you can
>   close the terminal and reopen it or you can source ~/.bashrc as shown
>   above.
>
> `source ~/.bashrc`
>
> Then log out and back in and try

```
apt-get update
```

Comment: To set the proxy to be used by `apt`, `apt-get`, Ubuntu Software Center,...  only the method involving `/etc/apt/apt-conf` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to set this up (with Squid) not too long go.

Once I had squid setup, I typed 'export http_proxy=0.0.0.0:3128 && export https_proxy=0.0.0.0:3128" where 0.0.0.0 is the IP address of the proxy server, and 3128 is the port number (default number for squid).

See if it works from command line. Then you could add it to your ~/.bashrc, unless you wanted the proxy available for all users.

Comment: Would i NEED to use squid? I would much rather not.

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to. I was more or less suggestion to try using export http_proce=<proxy>. Test with wget as well, I believe it tells you it's using a proxy. If wget is using a proxy, then you may have to do what Clive van Hilten suggested and specify proxy settings for apt-get.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue with Ubuntu Software or `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that was somewhat similar. I recently installed [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and my browsers worked fine before installing it.

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the browsers Im using are Google chrome and Mozilla firefox.

After restarting, I realized that neither browser works or connects to the internet. They were all displaying

> the proxy server is refusing connections

I then remembered that I installed [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and simply just opened it up again to get the browsers working again

Comment: That is not what the OP was reporting.